# Images not displaying when downloading with NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download images on a background thread. Upon completion of download I'm setting the image view's image property to be the newly downloaded image. I keep running into an issue where the image doesn't display in the cell when I download the image. I've tried laying out my views and also delegating to my vc to call `reloadData` and `reloadDataWithIndices` but to no avail

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:cellData.imageURL] completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (error) {
            return;
        }

        UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
        _imageView.image = downloadedImage;
        [self.delegate cellDidFinishLoadingImage:row];
        [self setNeedsLayout];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    });
}];
[getImageTask resume];
```

In `cellDidFinishLoadingImage:`

```
- (void)cellDidFinishLoadingImage:(NSInteger)row {
[_collectionView reloadData];
 }
```

Any idea's why this might be

If I don't include reloadData it seems only some of the images render. If I include reloadData it seems to flash different empty images along with the regular images and then the images disappear
[image: Some cells render with the image while others don't]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you call `[_collectionView reloadData];` you start the process again and lost previous changes (not sure the place where you initiate image downloading). I'll suggest you create some kind of cache like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSIndexPath *, UIImage *> *imageCach` and in cellForRow function check at first existing image for a specific cell, in case it exists - show it via `_imageView.image = self.imageCache[indexPath];`, otherwise download it as you do, but instead of showing, save it to cache `self.imageCache[indexPath] = downloadedImage;` and call `[self.delegate cellDidFinishLoadingImage:row];` which update cell with recently downloaded image

Comment: If that's the case why doesn't reloadItemsAtIndexPaths seem to work? I'm only loaded at a single index at a time yet it seems the image is still not displaying properly. Also if I don't reload data it seems none of the images show so it seems an issue whether I reload data or not

Comment: I'm seeing that the image download task at `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]` sometimes return nil even though there is no error

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue. The problem was I was using dispatch_async to go to back to the main queue when I should have used sync. I'm not entirely sure why delegating back and reloading an index path doesn't work but for now sync seems to work fine